# How do I measure the viscosity for different percentages of water contaminated oil?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, viscosity

I am a high school student and would like to investigate how the percentage of water affects the lubrication of oil (water contamination in engine oils can negatively on the performance of the engine and increase fuel consumption.). Within the constraints of a high school physics lab, how would I measure the lubrication of oil for different percentages of water contamination?

Comment: this is a complex problem. the answer depends on whether you are using *detergent oil* or *non-detergent* oil. Water cannot mix with nondetergent oil and so there will be no effect on the properties of the oil. Detergent oil will pick up and hold water that it comes in contact with but only until the engine has come up to full operating temperature, by which time the oil has become very hot and all the water has been boiled out of it. Which type of oil do you intent to test?

Comment: If water has no effect on the properties of non-detergent oil then I suppose I would test the properties of detergent oil instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can test the viscosity (relative to a known standard liquid) by putting a small hole in the bottom of a measuring cup and seeing how long it takes for the cup to empty with the liquid of choice. For small holes and slow flow rates the emptying time will be proportional to the viscosity.

The *lubricity* of water-contaminated oil is far more difficult to measure. I know of no way to do this in a high school lab.